# git clone with putty fails

Tags: git, putty

I'm trying to clone a git repository from bitbucket using ssh. It works nicely with https, but I keep getting the following result

```
> git clone git@bitbucket.org:PATH/TO/MY/REPOSITORY.git
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
Connection abandoned.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have pageant running with the right key and GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\plink.exe

Comment: Can you confirm that this `git@bitbucket.org:PATH/TO/MY/REPOSITORY.git` is exactly what you pass to `git clone` ?

Comment: PATH/TO/MY/REPOSITORY.git is not the real path. I got the real path from bitbucket using the "clone" action on the web page, which provides a string I can cut and paste into a command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept guessing at some kind of access right issue, but the real issue was the unknown host.

To fix that, simply do

```
putty git@bitbucket.org
```

This will launch a terminal window and a dialog that gives you the opportunity to accept the server fingerprint. After that, the previous clone command works as it is.